# Cannot put a working formula into array formula (SORT and FILTER are problematic)

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have tried to put this formula:

```
=JEŻELI(A2<>"";
  QUERY(
   SORT(   
    FILTER(abonamenty!A:G; abonamenty!B:B = D2; abonamenty!A:A <= A2); 
   1; FAŁSZ); 
 "SELECT Col7 LIMIT 1");
 "")
```

into arrayformula().
'Abonamenty' is a table with subscription rates.
Formula returns the latest subscription rate for customer ID stored in column B in 'abonamenty' that matches customer id in main sheet in B column.

The obvious :

```
=IF(A2:A<>"", QUERY(SORT(FILTER(abonamenty!A:G, abonamenty!B:B = D2:D, abonamenty!A:A <= A2:A), 1, FALSE), "SELECT Col7 LIMIT 1"), "")
```

Does not work. Chat GPT is, well... not helping :).

Any ideas?